# ELB_5xx errors but no application errors

Tags: amazon-elb

We see lot of ELB_5xx errors recently. During this time there is no error logged in the back end server, no HTTP 5xx errors , there is no 5xx errors in ELB logs and there is no application restart. But still ELB throws 5xx errors to the user and healthy host count reduced till 0 and resumed automatically.

It seems there is some issues while checking instance health check from ELB. I don't think we have any network issues between ELB and the application during healthcheck. Some of them saying that if we create new ELBs would resolve the issue because our ELBs are created long back. Is it true that if rotate the ELB would solve the issue. Please help me to resolve this issues.

Comment: What are the _exact_ HTTP 5xx response codes that your clients are receiving from your ELB?

Comment: 503 Gateway time out

Comment: "Gateway time out" is usually HTTP 504; HTTP 503 is usually "Service unavailable".  The distinction is important; 504s usually indicate either _a)_ your requests took longer than the ELB request timeout (defaults to 60 secs), which will **not** show up as errors in your server logs, or _b)_ the persistent connection from the ELB to your server was closed by the server (_e.g._ the maximum number of requests per connection was reached) while handling that client request.  503s, on other hand, usually indicate health check issues (timeouts, SSL issues, _etc_).

Comment: "ELB 5XXs" is not the same as "HTTP 5XXs". if you check on the monitoring, you will see 0 HTTP 5XXs, but multiple ELB 5XXs